# Defining aliases into a file freeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I've seen someone define an alias* in a file (he directly edited a file, and added the alias) in freeBSD, does anyone know which file this is?

I assume those where aliases because he gave them a name, and wrote a command for them, then called them in cli

Only thing that I fould related to aliases is :

```
alias alias_name "do_something"
```

And these do not show if I write alias in cli, the output is:

```
# alias
h       (history 25)
j       (jobs -l)
la      (ls -aF)
lf      (ls -FA)
ll      (ls -lAF)
```

The ones I defined don't show here

Which dosen't seem to stick, after I rebooted, the're gone

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, understoond, but should it remain considering the right answer has been provided?

Comment: No. Delete this and ask on one of the other sites. It doesn't belong here. It is not a programming question. People looking for this solution will be looking over there, not here.

Answer (score 0):

The file was csh resource script, editing it reveals alias like ll and so on:

```
ee ~/.cshrc
```